# Write changes on python file from html when using a flask server

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, raspberry-pi-zero

I have an issue that I am not able to solve. I am trying to make a sprinkler system and I want to disable or enable its run times by changing the value of a list:

```
zoneList = [
['Zone1', 17, .1, 'enable'],
['Zone2', 27, .1, 'disable']]
```

I make it work to change the value at the front-end, but it does not change on the back-end

This is my file structure:

```
app.py
zoneList.py
templates/
    config.html
```

This is the flask route:

```
@app.route('/config', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def config():
if request.method == 'POST':
    status = request.form['status']
    x=0
    for item in zoneList:
        if status == item[0]:
            if item[3] == 'enable':
                zoneList[x][3] = 'disable'
                return  redirect('/config')
            else:
                zoneList[x][3] = 'enable'
                return  redirect('/config')
        else:
            x+=1


return render_template('config.html', zoneList=zoneList)
```

and this is the html code:

```
{% for value in zoneList %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ value[0] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ value[1] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ value[2] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ value[3] }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <form method='POST'>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link text-primary" name='edit' value='configEdit'>                                     <i class='material-icons'>
                                        edit
                                    </i>
                                </button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link {{'text-success' if value[3]=='enable'}} {{'text-danger' if value[3]=='disable'}}" name='status' value={{value[0]}}>
                                    <i class='material-icons font-weight-bold'>
                                        power_settings_new
                                    </i>
                                </button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link text-dark" name='delete' value='delete'>
                                    <i class='material-icons'>
                                        delete
                                    </i>
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```

I know I'm missing something but I don't have too much experience. Maybe I should use a database instead, something like PostgreSql.

I'm using a Raspberry Pi Zero W for this project

Comment: Start using sqlite see here https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html. It is a light weight DB that comes out of the box with python. It requires basic SQL knowledge but it is the right direction to go.

Comment: @balderman I really appreciate your comment/help. I did what you said before and now I have it working with SQLite3.